# Cannot call the variable in formula

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, if-statement

I am doing this python programming and stuck with an issue. 
The program cannot call the value of the n_zero when I put it in the conditional statement.

Here's the program

```
import numpy as np

n_zero=int(input('Insert the amount of 0:  '))
n_one =int(input('Insert the amount of 1: '))
n_two =int(input('Insert the amount of 2: '))
n_three = int(input('Insert the amount of 3: '))

data = [0]*n_zero + [1]*n_one + [2]*n_two + [3]*n_three
print len(data)

if len(data)==(2(n_zero)-1):
    np.random.shuffle(data)
    datastring = ''.join(map(str, data))
    print ("Data string is : %s " % datastring )


else:
    print(error)
```

this is the error

```
    if len(data)==(2(n_zero)-1):
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Thank you

Comment: This error doesn't match with provided code. Please provide actual code.

Comment: sorry. Here's the error. 

 `if len(data)==(2(n_zero)-1):
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if len(data) == (2(n_zero) - 1):
```

should become:

```
if len(data) == (2 * (n_zero) - 1):
```

Note `*` in second example. You must explicitly provide operator, Python will not assume that You want to multiply those 2 numbers if You don't tell it.

Comment: Thank you! I forgot the asterisk

Answer (score 2):

In python you don't cast the left value variable as you don't specify the left value type.

```
n_zero=int(input('Insert the amount of 0:  '))
```

**Regarding your edit:**

What exactly are you trying to reach? if multiply than use the operator *

```
if len(data)==(2*(n_zero)-1):
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you! I forgot the asterisk